# question mark ? in verilog support multi bit select signal?

Tags: verilog

```
y = sel ? x : y
```

I always assume that ***sel*** should be a one bit data, 1 or 0, true or false.
But my teammates insist that *sel* can be more than one bit. He used the original 4 bit signal as sel instead, as long as its not 0, its ture, which means any bit goes high in ***sel*** it would output x.
I was surprised it passed the synthesis in Qaurtus. No errors

Normally we use y = |sel ? x: y instead.

what we want here is if any bits in ***sel*** is high, we want x as output.
Does this works fine in all kinds of verilog synthesis tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy. In Verilog, true is non-zero and false is 0, X or Z. The conditional operator `?:` only looks at true or false for the conditional select expression.